# Рекурсия как остановить

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Как должна заканчиваться рекурсия? выскакивает Previous line repeated 16 more times и RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, увеличивать глубину не поможет.

```
import time
a = 1

def start():
    time.sleep(1)
    print(a)
    if a == 1:
        print("start if", a)
        stop()
    else:
        print("start else")
        continues()

def stop():
    print("stop")

    if a == 2:
        print("stop if", a)
        start()
    else:
        print("stop else")
        continues()

def continues():

    if a == 1:
        print("continues")
        start()
    else:
        print("continues else")
        stop()
```

Comment: А где ваш код? Ну перестаньте вызвать функцию саму из себя, рекурсия и закончится.

Comment: а вот нужно чтоб функции вызывались! а можно  файл с кодом сам себя чтоб вызывал?

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия должна а) заканчиваться `return`, б) для двух разных условий `return` должен содержать разное. Один раз саму функцию (потому и рекурсия), другой раз какое-то фиксированное значение (как раз, чтобы рекурсия завершилась).

Comment: можно пример в этом примере как будет выглядеть?

Comment: а можно return stop()? и так в каждом иф елсе, будет это завершением рекурсии?

Comment: Нельзя, потому что непонятно, что этот пример делает.

Comment: пример для примера, для понимания заканчивания рекурсии, узнать как заканчивать рекурсию, но функции должны вызываться, чтоб не вылетала ошибка рекурсии!может сам скрипт как то перезапускать- является это концом рекурсии?

Comment: https://codecamp.ru/blog/python-recursion/

Comment: а if вложенный в While, try-except - тоже рекурсия?

Comment: "А коробка-автомат это тоже седан?" Примерно так звучит ваш вопрос. Возьмите учебник.